# SQL aggregation query, non linear cost

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, postgis

I'm doing a complex aggregation of some timeseris GPS data in a postgres 13 + postgis 3 + timescaleDB 2 database. The table I'm looking at has several million entries per day and I want to do an aggregation (one row per day, per gps_id, per group gap ID) for several months.

Lets say that I've created a function to perform the aggregation:

```
--pseudo code, won't actually work...
CREATE FUNCTION my_agg_func(starttime, endtime)
AS

WITH gps_window AS 
(SELECT gps.id,
        gps.geom,
        gps.time,
        -- find where there are 1 hour gaps in data 
        lag(ais.time) OVER (PARTITION BY gps.id ORDER BY gps.time) <= (gps.time - '01:00:00'::interval) AS time_step,
       -- find where there are 0.1 deg gaps in position
        st_distance(gps.geom, lag(gps.geom) OVER (PARTITION BY gps.id ORDER BY gps.time)) >= 0.1 AS dist_step
 FROM gps
 WHERE gps.time BETWEEN starttime AND endtime
), groups AS (
SELECT gps_window.id,
       gps_window.geom,
       gps_window.time,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE gps_window.time_step) OVER (PARTITION BY gps_window.id ORDER BY gps_window.time) AS time_grp,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE gps_window.dist_step) OVER (PARTITION BY gps_window.id ORDER BY gps_window.time) AS dist_grp
       FROM gps_window
      --get rid of duplicate points
      WHERE gps_window.dist > 0
      ) 
SELECT 
  gps_id,
  date(gps.time),
  time_grp,
  dist_grp
  st_setsrid(st_makeline(gps_window."position" ORDER BY gps_window.event_time), 4326) AS geom,
FROM groups
WHERE gps_time BETWEEN starttime AND endtime
GROUP BY gps.id, date(gps.time), time_grp, dist_grp
```

where the gap_id functions are checking for sequential gps points from the same gps_id that are too distant from each other, traveled unreasonably fast or the time between messages was too much. The aggregates are basically creating a line from the gps points. The end result of is a bunch of lines where all the points in the line are "reasonable".

To run the aggregation function for 1 day (starttime = '2020-01-01', endtime = '2020-01-02') it takes about 12 secs to complete. If I choose a week of data, it takes 10 minutes. If I choose a month of data it takes 15h+ to complete.

I would expect linear performance since the data is going to be grouped per day anyway but this isn't the case. The obvious way to get around this performance bottleneck would be to run this in a for loop:

```
for date in date_range(starttime, endtime):
    my_agg_func(date, date+1)
```

I can do this in Python but any ideas how to either get a for loop running in postgres or to alter the aggregation query to be linear?

Comment: `date(gps_time)` has to be calculated for every row so the GROUP BY operation can't take advantage of any indexes on it. The query is too slow to begin with. Are those fields covered by indexes? How many rows are there? In PostgreSQL you can create an index based on an expression, which should make this query  a lot faster

Comment: Typically a Calendar table is used to make date-based reporting a lot easier. A Calendar table contains one row per day for eg 10-20 years, with precalculated and indexed fields for year, month, day of week, semester, quarter, week number and their names. This way, instead of having to calculate semesters or period start and end days, you can just JOIN with that table on a Date column and filter on the desired period field. This still requires adding a `date` field to the tables you want to query

Comment: TimeScaleDB has some nifty functions for time-series queries but I think in my over-optimisation of the query I stopped using them... The table size is around 5.5M rows per day and there are indexes on time, gps_id, geom.

Comment: I'll edit the query to be more in line with what I'm actually doing.

Comment: The index on `gps_time` won't help though, because the query uses the results of `date(gps_time)`. Try creating an index on `date(gps_time)`

Comment: I've removed the date(time) section from the SQL I'm running. The times are better but I'm still not seeing a linear cost in performance when increasing the days. This make sense?

Comment: The query you posted now has *absolutely* nothing to do with the original simple query. It's impossible to guess what the performance will be except "maybe slow". What does the execution plan look like? All `OVER` clauses require sorting and unless the results are already ordered the same way as the `OVER` clause, another sort will be needed.

Comment: `st_distance(gps.geom, lag(ais.geom) ` can be another very slow operation, even with spatial indexes. A spatial index can find overlapping shapes, the same way a B+-Tree index can find overlapping ranges. You're calculating the distance between N^2 shapes though, which will always be slow. GIS systems can convert a distance query to a query that searches for any stored shapes intercepted by a polygon the same size as the required distance but this will still be slow if you try to calculate distances between lots of shapes

Comment: Given that part of my original question was "how do I do a loop in psql" I didn't really want to muddy the waters with complex queries that are hard to understand. Like you say,;it's impossible to guess on the performance of this query other than "its got lots of moving parts".

Comment: The actual query has nothing to do with the original though. And looping would only be faster because it simplified the query. *Simplify the query* from the start. In any case the `st_distance` calls will be slow whether you loop or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240312/discussion-between-redm-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation of time intervals (known as COLLAPSE operator in SQL litterature) leads to write complex queries whose execution cost can be exponential or polynomial depending on the method used. The old classical SQL formulations of SNODGRASS or Chris Date are exponential. Recently Itzik Ben Gan, a Microsoft SQL Server MVP write a polynomial form which gives excellent response times, but uses the CROSS APPLY, operator invented by Microsoft and since taken over by Oracle ... The queries are as follows:

```
WITH 
C1 AS (SELECT ITV_ITEM, ITV_DEBUT AS ts, +1 AS genre, NULL AS e,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITV_ITEM ORDER BY ITV_DEBUT) AS s
       FROM   T_INTERVAL_ITV
       UNION  ALL
       SELECT ITV_ITEM, ITV_FIN AS ts, -1 AS genre, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITV_ITEM ORDER BY ITV_FIN) AS e,
              NULL AS s
       FROM T_INTERVAL_ITV),
C2 AS (SELECT C1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITV_ITEM ORDER BY ts, genre DESC) 
                 AS se
       FROM   C1),
C3 AS (SELECT ITV_ITEM, ts, 
              FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITV_ITEM ORDER BY ts) - 1) / 2 + 1) 
                 AS grpnum
       FROM   C2
       WHERE  COALESCE(s - (se - s) - 1, (se - e) - e) = 0),
C4 AS (SELECT ITV_ITEM, MIN(ts) AS ITV_DEBUT, max(ts) AS ITV_FIN
       FROM C3
       GROUP BY ITV_ITEM, grpnum)
SELECT A.ITV_ITEM, A.ITV_DEBUT, A.ITV_FIN
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ITV_ITEM 
        FROM   T_INTERVAL_ITV) AS U
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   C4
                    WHERE  ITV_ITEM = U.ITV_ITEM) AS A
ORDER BY ITV_ITEM, ITV_DEBUT, ITV_FIN;
```

[image: Different formulae of time aggregation]

Can you transform this MS SQL Server specific query by using the LATERAL join ? This will help you to have a better execution time.

Comment: The query contains spatial operations too. It's not just time intervals